# Custom Shell C program: After child process finishes, why does my process turn into a zombie?

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, operating-system

So I am writing my own shell in a C program (basically same as bash) and I am working on the sleep command. I want to be able to run the sleep command in the background, thus if I type in "sleep 10 &", it will be nonblocking and allow me to continue using the shell.

BUT when the background sleep command finishes (after 10 seconds), instead of terminating, it turns into a zombie process, why? I want it to just be completely gone.

Also, how do I print a message AFTER the background process has finished running?

Below is my sleep function that just calls the execl function:

```
void sleepFunc(char *secondsInput)
{
    char *bin_path = "/bin/sleep";
    char *args[] = {bin_path, secondsInput, NULL};
    execl("/bin/sleep", "sleep", secondsInput, NULL);
    perror("execl");
}
```

Below is my code that forks a child process and uses child process to call the sleep function:

```
int childStatus;
                pid_t childPid = fork();
                int childProcess_pid;
                if (childPid == -1)
                {
                    perror("fork() failed!");
                    exit(1);
                    break;
                }
                else if (childPid == 0)
                {
                    // Child process executes this branch
                    childProcess_pid = getpid();
                    sleepFunc(secondsInput);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // The parent process executes this branch
                    printf("background pid is %d\n", childPid);
                    // WNOHANG specified. If the child hasn't terminated, waitpid will immediately return with value 0
                    childPid = waitpid(childPid, &childStatus, WNOHANG);
                    printf("Background process %s has completed!\n", childPid); // I want this print statement to print only AFTER the background process completes (so after x amount of seconds)
                }
            }
```

My output is shown below. First "ps" command is executed immediately after typing "sleep 10 &", and the second "ps" command is executed after 10 seconds. Child process becomes a zombie, and nothing gets printed to the terminal letting me know it has completed. Any suggestions?

```
: sleep 10 &
background pid is 52002
In the parent process waitpid returned value 0
: ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
45433 ttys001    0:00.50 -zsh
25223 ttys003    0:08.71 /bin/zsh -l
51996 ttys003    0:00.00 ./a.out
52002 ttys003    0:00.00 sleep 10
: ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
45433 ttys001    0:00.50 -zsh
25223 ttys003    0:08.71 /bin/zsh -l
51996 ttys003    0:00.00 ./a.out
52002 ttys003    0:00.00 (sleep)
:
```

Comment: Because you use the `WNOHANG` flags, the parent process doesn't actually wait for the child process to exit, and instead let it turn into a zombie.

Comment: But I need my program to continue running and prompting the user to enter in a command. How could I get around that?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I specifically said I wanted to run this sleep process in the BACKGROUND. How do I do that and NOT have my shell waiting around for it to complete??

Comment: Then the best solution is to catch the `SIGCHLD` signal, and reap the child when that happens.

Comment: ok thank you, can you point me in the right direction as to how I can implement that?